# Exit bash script if git remote main is ahead of current local branch

Tags: bash, git

I have a script in a remote main branch. Multiple users will clone the repo and might modify the script locally. Nobody, though, besides myself will update the remote main version.
I need to make sure that users cannot run their local version of the script (which they might have on any local modified or unmodified branch) if remote main is ahead. I.e., the script should exit if there are remote changes not merged locally into the current branch, which will encourage users to pull and merge the changes manually. No auto-merging should happen as that might create some unnecessary conflicts.

In the example below what should I do to get `status`?

```
current_branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
status=`git check if origin/main is now ahead of $current_branch`
if [[ $status ]]; then
  echo Please merge changes from origin/main
  exit 1
fi
continue business logic
```

PS: This is in a collaborative setup. E.g., I don't need to worry about users removing this check.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question yet you raise many. What have you tried so far? In what language is your script even in (or: supposed to be written in)? It seems as if you hadn't put any effort into this question. Even if that isn't true, the smell of XY problem is strong.

Comment: @Friedrich, well the title clearly says bash. I added a code snippet.

Comment: `status=$(git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/main $current_branch)`

Comment: Thanks, @Shachar297! But the following command does print or return anything: `git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/main $current_branch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to test against fork point :

```
fp=$(git merge-base origin/main HEAD)
if test $fp != $(git rev-parse origin/main); then
    echo Please merge changes from origin/main
    exit 1
fi
```